# Is Target Disk Mode… dead?

Tags: thunderbolt, target-disk-mode

Been using Target Disk Mode for the last 15 years flawlessly, except for the last 2-3 years.
Yesterday I needed to copy a bunch of files between my 16" Intel and a brand new 14" M1 Pro. Target Disk Mode didn't work.

Tried with:
4 Macs (Intel macOS 12.4; Intel macOS 13; M1 macOS 12.4; M1 macOS 13) - FileVault disabled, all APFS.
3 different Thunderbolt/USB-C cables (Apple, Amazon, no-name)
All Macs were tested both in Target Disk Mode ("slave") or as receivers ("master")

I tried all possible permutations, none work. No Mac can see another Target Disk Mode (not visible in Disk Utility or with `diskutil list`, connected hardware not listed under Thunderbolt or Storage device in System Info).

I also tried to setup a direct Thunderbolt Bridge between two running computers, by plugging them directly with a TB cable and setting up static IPv4 addresses in an unused range, to no avail. The network connection stays "Not Connected" and is never brought up, whatever the cable I use.

Is Target Disk Mode… basically dead??

Comment: Only a comment, since i don't know more technical details: Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode: `With the Mac transition to Apple silicon, Apple replaced Target Disk Mode with Mac Sharing Mode.`

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it; but rebooting my M1 in Mac Sharing Mode according to the process, then plugging it in another Mac results in… nothing.

Comment: [This Apple document](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/12.0/mac/12.0) explains how to enable sharing mode. Don't think it will show up in Disk Utility etc though, do you not see the M1 on your Intel Mac as described in step 7?

Comment: I don't. And what's more: when I put an Intel Mac in TDM (T at boot, logo clearly visible on screen) and plug it in another Intel Mac — like I've done for years — nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure the cable you use is good? If you have others, try those.

Comment: I've tried three different cables.